# Test if a foreign key is None or not

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in django that points to another model. I want to test if it's set to something or not.

```
model.foreignkey = ForeignKeyField(...)
```

I want to test if this foreignkey is set or not - without actually fetching the foreign row's data (if the foreign key is set).

```
if model.foreignkey: # This line fetches data for 
    <dosomething>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test for model.foreignkey_id

Check out the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation